# No reverse match error from django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView

Tags: django, django-2.0

This should be simple enough, but after spending multiple hours trying to figure this out, reviewing past code, and searching for answers online, I am out of ideas.

Browser Error message:

```
NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login/ Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is 
not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/
Django Version: 2.1
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: C:\Anaconda3\envs\bookmarks\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 622
Python Executable:  C:\Anaconda3\envs\bookmarks\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.6
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\raine\\PycharmProjects\\Mapt\\bookmarks\\bookmarks',
 'C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\bookmarks\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\bookmarks\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\bookmarks\\lib',
 'C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\bookmarks',
 'C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\bookmarks\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 7 Aug 2018 21:29:41 +0000
```

The project tree:

```
bookmarks
    ├───accounts
    │   ├───migrations
    │   │   └───__pycache__
    │   ├───templates
    │   │   └───accounts
    │   └───__pycache__
    ├───bookmarks
    │   └───__pycache__
    ├───static
    │   └───css
    └───templates
```

bookmarks/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts'))
]
```

which redirects to accounts/urls.py .  I don't expect my error because I'ved assigned the name 'login' in the url path.

```
app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', 
         auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html'),
         name='login'),
    path('logout/', 
         auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='accounts/logout.html'), 
         name='logout'),
]
```

I am especially confused since the LogoutView works, and the LoginView does not. I've reviewed code from some other projects that accomplish the same thing and can't spot any differences that would lead me to my current error.  Very curious.  The error does not lead me to believe there is a problem with my templates, but here they are, nonetheless.

accounts/login.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% block title %} Login {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Login</h1>
<p>Please use this form to login.</p>
<form class="form" method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {% buttons %}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{next}}" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit
    </button>
    {% endbuttons %}
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

accounts/logout.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Logout</h1>
<p>You have successfully logged out.</p>
<a href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}">Didn't mean to log out?  Log back in.</a>

{% endblock content %}
```

Help & feedback would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Is  `url` in this line `<a href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}">Didn't mean to log out?  Log back in.</a>` supposed to be there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to mention URL namespace in `accounts/login.html` form's `action` attribute
`{% url 'accounts:login' %}`